# How to split a dataframe with multiple values in the same row, with strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I read my pandas dataframe as:

ERA5RS12 = pd.read_csv('F:/ERA5_RS/[12]-PIRATA-2017_20171127_100021/wspd_hl.csv')

ERA5RS12

[My output is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40UaR.png)

I want some like this:

Latitude,Longitude,Value,Level

9,33,8.4,20

9,33,10,40

9,33,11,100

Comment: You need to check the delimiter in your original csv, and assign it in your ```read_csv```

Comment: When posting pandas related question, please, [follow the convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the delimiter of your CSV file is `,`. Otherwise, you can specify a custom delimiter corresponding to the file with parameter `sep` while calling `pd.read_csv`. see [a documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv).

**Edited**:
According to the Excel file you provided, I convert it to CSV format. Here is a snippet to produce what you need.

```py
import pandas as pd

with open("wspd_hl.csv", "r") as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=lines[0].split(" "))
for i, line in enumerate(lines[1:], 1):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        line = line.replace(",", "")
        df.loc[len(df)] = [value for value in line.split(" ") if value.strip() != ""]
```

Output:

| index | Latitude | Longitude | Value | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 6.6732 | 20 |
| 1 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 6.8282 | 30 |
| 2 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 6.9814 | 50 |
| 3 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 7.0756 | 70 |
| 4 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 7.1705 | 100 |
| 5 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 7.2190 | 120 |
| 6 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 7.2613 | 140 |
| 7 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 7.2989 | 160 |
| 8 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 7.3352 | 180 |
| 9 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 7.3685 | 200 |
| 10 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 7.4524 | 250 |
| 11 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 7.5457 | 300 |
| 12 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 7.6750 | 350 |
| 13 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 7.9962 | 400 |
| 14 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 8.3183 | 450 |
| 15 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 8.4191 | 500 |
| 16 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 8.3831 | 550 |
| 17 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 8.2993 | 600 |
| 18 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 8.3508 | 650 |
| 19 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 8.4924 | 700 |
| 20 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 8.6865 | 750 |
| 21 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 8.9590 | 800 |
| 22 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 9.2247 | 850 |
| 23 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 9.4725 | 900 |
| 24 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 9.6867 | 950 |
| 25 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 9.8466 | 1000 |
| 26 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 10.1283 | 1100 |
| 27 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 10.4210 | 1200 |
| 28 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 10.7595 | 1300 |
| 29 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 11.1359 | 1400 |
| 30 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 11.5150 | 1500 |
| 31 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 11.8761 | 1600 |
| 32 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 12.5596 | 1800 |
| 33 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 12.8827 | 1900 |
| 34 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 13.2004 | 2000 |
| 35 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 13.5117 | 2200 |
| 36 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 13.3459 | 2400 |
| 37 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 12.7713 | 2600 |
| 38 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 11.9837 | 2800 |
| 39 | 9.000 | 321.990 | 11.1624 | 3000 |

Comment: I've tried, but the file opens with the strings latitude, longitude, value and level repeated on each line.

Comment: @WilliamJacondino Can you provide the CSV file?

Comment: Sure. Here is the link: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvO08oBWX0Vtg9VMmHxwEhQHMI5r0A?e=4LvEoh

Comment: Thank you very much. I have several files that I need to open that are in this format, if I need to adapt a loop so I don't have to repeat all the code above is there an easier way to read multiple csv files in that same format?

Comment: @WilliamJacondino you can wrap the code into a function and pass file paths one by one inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would write my own reader to read data like this. With the following code, you can have your column names in `header` list, and your table rows in `lines` list.

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as file:
    
    header = []
    lines = []
    
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        
        if i == 0:
            header = line.split()
            continue
            
        if i % 2 == 0:
            continue
            
        lines.append(line.split())
```

When the data are processed, you can easily create `pd.DataFrame`, and clean the data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=header)
df['Value'] = df.Value.str.strip(',').astype(float)
```

The result is following.

```
>> df.head()
  Latitude Longitude   Value level
0    9.000   321.990  6.6732    20
1    9.000   321.990  6.8282    30
2    9.000   321.990  6.9814    50
3    9.000   321.990  7.0756    70
4    9.000   321.990  7.1705   100
```

**EDIT**

If you want to reuse the code above, you can wrap it up and create a function.

```
def read_data(csv_file_path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Read data, process them and return data frame."""
    with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as file:
        
        header = []
        lines = []
        
        for i, line in enumerate(file):
            
            if i == 0:
                header = line.split()
                continue
                
            if i % 2 == 0:
                continue
                
            lines.append(line.split())

    df = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=header)
    df['Value'] = df.Value.str.strip(',').astype(float)

    return df
```

Then the function can be used like this.

```
>> df = read_data('/path/to/test.csv')
>> df.head()
  Latitude Longitude   Value level
0    9.000   321.990  6.6732    20
1    9.000   321.990  6.8282    30
2    9.000   321.990  6.9814    50
3    9.000   321.990  7.0756    70
4    9.000   321.990  7.1705   100
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have several files that I need to open that are in this format, if I need to adapt a loop so I don't have to repeat all the code above is there an easier way to read multiple csv files in that same format?

Comment: @WilliamJacondino I have edited my answer with function wrapper that can be reused for other CSV files. <3

Comment: Thank you very much, Jaroslav Bezděk! I was editing path by path for each file I needed to open yesterday, but now with this function the code will be smaller. Thank you so!